# LoadRunner application logout issue

Tags: loadrunner

I have an online application that I'm attempting to load test with HP LoadRunner and I would like it to logout of the application at the end.
Here is the code that LoadRuuner recored for the logout process:

```
web_custom_request("j_spring_security_logout", 
    "URL=https://micssda.state.mi.us:4023/ml01guideline/j_spring_security_logout", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "Referer=https://micssda.state.mi.us:4023/ml01guideline/guideline/resultsPage/load.html", 
    "Snapshot=t14.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    "EncType=", 
    LAST);
```

When I try to play back this code however I get: Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "https://micssda.state.mi.us:4023/ml01guideline/"   [MsgId: MERR-26612]

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  I've looked at the webpage code to see that the button is calling the logout function, which has the following code:

```
function logout() {
    url = staticResourceUrl + "/j_spring_security_logout";

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url
    });
    window.close();
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Check your HTTP access logs.  You may be receiving this error live but it is not observed because the window is closed as part of the logout.

Comment: Have you correlated the sessions properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the application it self was throwing the HTTP 500 and we couldn't manually see it due to the window closing.